# How to assign vertex groups and bone weights through Blender's Python API?

Tags: python, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I'm making a script to import custom objects, it is still at early stage but so far vertices, faces and uv are created correctly. I want to do weight painting through Blender's Python API but I don't know how to do it properly.

Below an extract of the code that create the objects, how I could add vertex group and relative weights? I know how to extract vertex indices and weights from the input model but don't know how to use them,

(Blender version is 2.72)

```
    for i in range(0,self. subsetCount):
        subset = self.subset[i]
        coords = subset.getV3(0)
        faces = subset.getIndices()
        me = bpy.data.meshes.new(subset.name+"_Mesh")

        ob = bpy.data.objects.new(str(i).zfill(2)+'_'+subset.name, me)
        ob.location = (0, 0, 0)
        bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)

        me.from_pydata(coords, [], faces)
        me.update(calc_edges=True)

        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(subset.name)
        mat.diffuse_color = (random.uniform(0.0, 1.0), \
                             random.uniform(0.0, 1.0), \
                             random.uniform(0.0, 1.0))
        me.materials.append(mat)

        for f in me.polygons:
            f.material_index = 0
            f.use_smooth = 1

        # vert_uvs = subset.getV2(0x28)
        # if len(vert_uvs) > 0:
        #     me.uv_textures.new("UV0")
        #     uvlist = [uv for pair in [vert_uvs[l.vertex_index] for l in me.loops] for uv in pair]
        #     me.uv_layers[-1].data.foreach_set("uv", uvlist)
```

**edit**

found this to add the group:

```
        vxgroup = ob.vertex_groups.new("group")
```

still don't know how to set weights for vertices (best would be at once)

**edit**

I was hoping to use something like a `foreach_set` but can't figure out how to use it, instead solved this way:

```
        for grp in ob.vertex_groups:
            grp.add(range(0,len(me.vertices)), 1.0, 'REPLACE')
```

is just an example and set all vertices weight in all groups of the object `ob` (if you try it in console select another mesh then back to see the weights applied).

Comment: You can read vertex weights like `ob.data.vertices[#].groups[#].weight`, but the problem is that there is no way to add groups to `.groups` on the object level. Thus, `VertexGroup.add()` is the only way. You should post your 2nd edit as answer! Also, try `ob.data.update()`, it might help to make the applied weights visible immediately.

Comment: @CoDEmanX thank you for the clarification and the tip about *update*, I will (post as answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vertex_groups` method `.add()` first argument is a list of vertices index, I  *group* my input to reduce the calls to `add` to the minimum necessary.

Note: my input weights are stored in unsigned bytes (0-255).

First with a dict `{grpID: ...}` then another dict as value for weights `{grpId: {weight: ...}}`, finally the list of vertices id `{grpId: {weight: [vxId, ...]}}`, at this point the code is quite simple:

```
        weights = myGetWeights()
        for grpId, wv in weights.items():
            grpName = "Bone_"+str(grpId).zfill(3)
            ob.vertex_groups.new(grpName)
            for weight, vxIdList  in wv.items():
                ob.vertex_groups[grpName].add(vxIdList, 1.0 / 255 * weight, 'REPLACE')
```